# Is it wise to choose a better journal with lesser number of similar papers?

Tags: publications, journals

I need to choose between two journals for my article. Both candidates are, in principle, suitable for the topic. One of them has a (considerably) larger number of articles similar to mine but the other one is a better journal in my opinion. The first one is a journal of both research articles and educational articles. Whereas the second one is a journal of purely new research.

My article is about the re-derivation of a very well-known result using fewer axioms. Thus, it is new research but might be more appreciated by a community engaged in both research and education. So, I am confused as to which one to choose. Personally, if both the journals were ready to accept my article, then I would choose the second one (the one with only research articles) for its more serious tone and thus, for the possibility of my article getting more serious attention.

But I think I need to make a choice incorporating the chances of acceptance as well.

Comment: As it stands your question cannot be answered by us, as weighing rejection risk and journal quality strongly on the quality of your paper and the journals, both of which we do not know. (See also [this meta post](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3406).) We might answer what to take into account when making such a decision, but you seem to have identified the key factors already.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Would it be appropriate and helpful if I spell out the names of the journals and a brief crux of my article? Of course, the details of my article would matter but would this much be helpful to even some extent?

Comment: *Would it be appropriate and helpful if I spell out the names of the journals and a brief crux of my article?* – Not really. We cannot judge the quality of your article, and we do not want to. See the section *Questions on research and publishing decisions* of the linked meta post.

Comment: You could still submit to Journal 1 if Journal 2 rejects it, right?  And if so, does Journal 2 have any information about how long their initial decision to accept/reject tends to take?

Comment: @Nat Yes, that is, of course, a possible way, but it usually takes around more than 4-5 months since the submission for the journal (any of them) to accept or reject a manuscript. Due to personal academic reason, I do not want to afford the worst case of 10 months before an acceptance (or well, rejection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask colleagues more experienced than you, ideally colleagues with experience of submitting to those journals, what they think of your chances.

If there is a question of whether your article fits in the scope of a journal, you could also ask an editor whether they would welcome a submission such as yours.

Usually, though, it will end up being a judgement call. You could, of course, submit to your top choice, and then go with the other one if your paper gets rejected. This is quite commonly done, even if the top journal is a long shot. However, this takes a lot of time and effort, and in my opinion it is often not as good a use of your time as getting something punished quickly and moving on to new work.

Comment: Yes, I am already getting exhausted with this stupid work of choosing a journal rather than indulging into something exciting with that time. In addition, I think--academically--I cannot afford the time that it would take in the process of submitting to two journals one after the other and waiting for them. So, probably I would go with the second journal. Thanks for your input!